# Тире в предложении "У меня много хороших друзей, но моя лучшая подруга — Аня"

Tags: пунктуация, тире

> У меня много хороших друзей, но моя лучшая подруга — Аня.

Нужно ли тире в этом предложении?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно, это тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженными именительным падежом существительных.

Answer (score 2):

**У меня много хороших друзей, но моя лучшая подруга — Аня.**

Здесь тире нужно (И.п. существительных для подлежащего и сказуемого, основное правило).

В разговорном стиле допускается пропуск тире, например: **А кто твой брат? — Мой брат учитель.**

Но в приведенном примере **вариант без тире** будет восприниматься как приложение перед определяемым слово (***моя лучшая подруга Аня***), а не как предложение.